# How to launch fragment from other app "package_name"

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

i want to open a fragment from an other **"Application 1"** and show it in **"Application 2"**, 
i know if i want to call an activity i use this code :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.app1", "com.app1.MainActivity"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

but now i want to use a fragment not activity!
How can i do it please ?

i tried to use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainActivity()).commit();
```

but it didn't work.